# Netsuite Saved Search Based On Transaction Frequency

Tags: netsuite

I've been asked to search NetSuite for customers that, due to a bug, may have been invoiced on a weekly frequency instead of a monthly frequency despite being set to a Monthly Billing Frequency on their Contract Line.

I've started with a customer search and have gotten this far:

Contract : Usage Billing Freq is Monthly
Transaction : Type is Invoice

I know how I'd approach this in SQL, but I'm lost in NetSuite. I'm assuming it would be some kind of Formula involving **Transaction : Date**, but despite searching around I can't figure out how to build this. Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a "customer" search with:

Columns:

- Field->Name; Summary type->Group
- Field->Transaction:Date; Summary type->Group; Function->Month
- Field->Transaction:Internal ID; Summary type->Count;

Standard filters (Criteria->Standard):

- Contract : Usage Billing Freq is Monthly
- Transaction : Type is Invoice

Summary filters (Criteria->Summary):

- Summary type->Count; Field->Transaction:Internal ID; Description-> is greater than 1

This will give you all problematic customers month by month, and will have nice drill-down when you click on customer name (you will be able to see all invoices in the specific month.

**Another option is:**

Columns:

- Field->Name; Summary type->Group
- Field->Transaction:Internal ID; Summary type->Count;

Standard filters (Criteria->Standard):

- Contract : Usage Billing Freq is Monthly
- Transaction : Type is Invoice
- Transaction : Date is within this month

Summary filters (Criteria->Summary):

- Summary type->Count; Field->Transaction:Internal ID; Description-> is greater than 1